# Initializing stored procedure output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRowCount

(
@count int=0 OUTPUT
)

AS
Select * from Emp where age>30;
SET @count=@count+@@ROWCOUNT;

RETURN
```

I am trying to initialize and access the output parameter in the following C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=answers;Integrated Security=True";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.CommandText = "GetRowCount";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@count", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@count"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters["@count"].Value=5;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

int ans = (int)(cmd.Parameters["@count"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(ans);
```

But on running the code, an `InvalidCastException` is being thrown at the second last line of the code (I debugged and checked that nothing is being returned in the Value attribute).

How can I properly initialize the output parameter in code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing SQL Server stored procedure output parameter in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174399/accessing-sql-server-stored-procedure-output-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I am the one who asked that question just about an hour ago, but this is a completely different problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the ParameterDirection to `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`

Have a look here for an example: [how to get return value from procedure sql server 2005 to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298822/how-to-get-return-value-from-procedure-sql-server-2005-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to initialize an `output` parameter.  Use `ParameterDirection.InputOutput` to pass the value to the stored procedure.

The most likely cause for a type exception is that the procedure returns `DBNull.Value`.  You can test that like:

```
var ans = cmd.Parameters["@count"].Value as int?;
```