# Input - Output parameter in same call to stored procedure - C#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

```
using (var con = connection)
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Students", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter sp = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIDs", studentId);
                    sp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

I am inputing a value to stored procedure but in this case i want to get a value back too. How can i incorporate output in above code?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Students
      @StudentId Students READONLY,
      @NumberOfStudents INT OUTPUT,
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing stored procedure output parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175932/initializing-stored-procedure-output-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
using (var con = connection)
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Students", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter sp = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentIDs", studentId);
        sp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        SqlParameter code = new SqlParameter("@NumberOfStudents", SqlDbType.Int);
        code.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(code);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Getting output value
        int NumberOfStudent = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@NumberOfStudents"].Value);

    }
}
```

Thanks

Manoj